# Data not showing up in global environment in Visual Studio Code with R extension

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, vscode-r

I am using Visual Studio Code with the R extension, but I’m having trouble getting my data to show up in the global environment. When I run a script that creates a data frame, I can see the output in the console, but the data frame is not visible in the global environment tab.
[issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nNsY.png)

I also get the following error messages in the Problems panel:

- Cannot register 'r.rpath.windows'. This property is already registered.
- Cannot register 'r.rpath.mac'. This property is already registered.
- Cannot register 'r.rpath.linux'. This property is already registered.

Here is the content of my settings.json file:

- "r.rpath.mac": "/usr/local/bin/r",
- "r.bracketedPaste": true,
- "r.rterm.mac": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/radian",
- "r.plot.useHttpgd": true,
- "r.workspaceViewer.showObjectSize": true

Can anyone help me fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue sometimes but without the error messages in problems panel. It's usually solved after restarting vscode.

Answer (score 1):

From your image, I see in the status bar that R has not been attached to active terminal: `R:(not attached)`.
Try to click on the icon and attach R to active terminal. If your current R is attached (e.g, if you see some thing like R 4.3.1 or the R version currently installed on your system), then from the `primary side bar` in the right side of the `vscode` click on `R icon` and look up the `Global Environment` under `Workspace` where the data are stored. You must see the data there.

```
#Or
```

If the option above doesn't successful, `try to kill the current terminal and go to the terminal menu and create new terminal`.

I had similar issue and was able to solve the issue as what I explained.
Hope these could help.